# Java Eclipse e3 to e4: How do I draw the folders I have created in an e3 application inside a composite?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have an application where I need to draw the following:

Application A:

```
    == MENU ==============================================
    ======================= BANNER =======================
    ======================================================
    | LEFT VIEW |                 TOP VIEW               |
    |           |                                        |
    |           |                                        |
    |           |                                        |
    |           |                                        |
    |           |                                        |
    |           |                                        |
    |           |========================================|
    |           |               BOTTOM VIEW              |
    |           |                                        |
    |           |                                        |
    ======================= BANNER =======================
    ======================================================
```

At the moment, the window looks as follows:

Application B:

```
    == MENU ==============================================
    ===========================
    | LEFT VIEW |  TOP VIEW   |
    |           |             |
    |           |             |
    |           |=============|
    |           | BOTTOM VIEW |
    |           |             |
    ===========================
    ======================= BANNER =======================


                          [COMPOSITE]


    ======================= BANNER =======================
    ======================================================
```

We need to take the the views and draw them in between the banners, as seen Application A.  The views are created via the IFolderLayout interface.  The banners are drawn via a composite.  Is there a way by which we can transfer the drawing of the views to the composite that lies in between the two banners in the Application B?  We are using the Eclipse RCP 4 framework.

Comment: If you are still using `IFolderLayout` you are still using e3. An e4 application would be using an Application.e4xmi - are you doing that?

Comment: This is an attempt to bring our project from rcp 3 to rcp 4 so I was hoping to use the compatibility layer for an easy transition, however the last part missing from being a full transition is that banner which used some 3->4 deprecated functions (createCoolBarControl, createMenuBar, createPageComposite, createStatusLineControl) has now stopped working. We got most of the code running but as you see from application B, we need to move the banner.